# how to create a oracle function in snowflake with cursors and loops?

Tags: oracle, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to transform this Oracle function to snowflake function. Honestly I don't have much experience in Snowflake. Could someone please help me on this. Thanks.

in `RETURN L_SN_CONCAT` we are expecting the concatenation of the all the values using the arguments we pass inside this function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION C3BL_HADOOP.GET_SN_CONCAT (
   P_ID1_I          NUMBER,
   P_ID2_I          NUMBER,
   P_SN_TYPE_I      VARCHAR2,
   P_DELIMITER_I    VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   CURSOR C_SHIP_SN
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT NVL ( (SELECT ACTUAL_SERIAL_NO
                               FROM XXCCS_BOP_SN_CROSS_REF
                              WHERE DUM_ID = SERIAL.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER),
                           TRIM (SERIAL.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER))
                         FM_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM XXCCS_BOP_OE_SHIP_LINES_SN  SERIAL,
             XXCCS_BOP_OE_SHIPMENT_LINES SHIP
       WHERE     SHIP.DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID = SERIAL.DELIVERY_DETAIL_ID
             AND SHIP.LINE_ID = P_ID1_I
      UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT NVL ( (SELECT ACTUAL_SERIAL_NO
                               FROM XXCCS_BOP_SN_CROSS_REF
                              WHERE DUM_ID = XOSL.SERIAL_NUMBER),
                           TRIM (XOSL.SERIAL_NUMBER))
                         FM_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM XXCCS_BOP_OE_SHIPMENT_LINES XOSL
       WHERE XOSL.LINE_ID = P_ID1_I;

   CURSOR C_RECEIPT_SN
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT NVL ( (SELECT ACTUAL_SERIAL_NO
                               FROM XXCCS_BOP_SN_CROSS_REF
                              WHERE DUM_ID = SERIAL_NUM),
                           TRIM (SERIAL_NUM))
                         SERIAL_NUM
        FROM XXCCS_BOP_OE_RCPT_LINES_SN
       WHERE SHIPMENT_LINE_ID = P_ID1_I AND TRANSACTION_ID = P_ID2_I;

   CURSOR C_CUST_SN
   IS
      SELECT DISTINCT
             NVL (TRIM (ATTRIBUTE9), TRIM (FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER))
                FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM XXCCS_BOP_OE_LOT_SERIAL_NUM -- XXCCS_BOP_OE_LOT_SERIAL_NUM -- USE XXCCS_BOP_O.OE_LOT_SERIAL_NUMBERS_R11@CSFPRD_BAC_APPSRO FOR R11 DATA
       WHERE LINE_ID = P_ID1_I;

   /*CURSOR C_CUST_SN
   IS
      SELECT FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM OE_LOT_SERIAL_NUMBERS_R11
       WHERE SHIPMENT_LINE_ID = P_ID1_I;*/

   CURSOR C_SPARE_SN
   IS
      SELECT NVL (TRIM (ATTRIBUTE9), TRIM (FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER))
                FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER
        FROM XXCCS_BOP_OE_LOT_SERIAL_NUM
       WHERE LINE_ID = P_ID1_I;

   L_START       NUMBER := 0;
   L_SN_CONCAT   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
   IF P_SN_TYPE_I = 'SHIP'
   THEN
      FOR C_SN_CUR IN C_SHIP_SN
      LOOP
         IF L_START = 0
         THEN
            IF C_SN_CUR.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT := C_SN_CUR.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER;
            END IF;
         ELSE
            IF C_SN_CUR.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT :=
                  L_SN_CONCAT || P_DELIMITER_I || C_SN_CUR.FM_SERIAL_NUMBER;
            END IF;
         END IF;

         L_START := L_START + 1;
      END LOOP;
   ELSIF P_SN_TYPE_I = 'RECEIPT'
   THEN
      FOR C_SN_CUR IN C_RECEIPT_SN
      LOOP
         IF L_START = 0
         THEN
            IF C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT := C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM;
            END IF;
         ELSE
            IF C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT :=
                  L_SN_CONCAT || P_DELIMITER_I || C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM;
            END IF;
         END IF;

         L_START := L_START + 1;
      END LOOP;
   ELSIF P_SN_TYPE_I = 'CUST'
   THEN
      FOR C_SN_CUR IN C_CUST_SN
      LOOP
         IF L_START = 0
         THEN
            IF C_SN_CUR.FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT := C_SN_CUR.FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER;
            END IF;
         ELSE
            IF C_SN_CUR.FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
            THEN
               L_SN_CONCAT :=
                  L_SN_CONCAT || P_DELIMITER_I || C_SN_CUR.FROM_SERIAL_NUMBER;
            END IF;
         END IF;

         L_START := L_START + 1;
      END LOOP;
END IF;

   RETURN (L_SN_CONCAT);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN (L_SN_CONCAT);
END GET_SN_CONCAT;
/
```

I tried this above query with slight modification according to snowflake function but getting error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CX_DB.CX_GSLOBAC_STG.TEMP_DEVA_GET_SN_CONCAT 
(  "P_ID1_I"          NUMBER,
   "P_ID2_I"          NUMBER,
   --P_SN_TYPE_I      VARCHAR,
   "P_DELIMITER_I"    VARCHAR)
   RETURNS VARCHAR
   LANGUAGE SQL
as
$$
DECLARE

C_RECEIPT_SN CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT DISTINCT NVL (a.ACTUAL_SERIAL_NO,
                TRIM (b.SERIAL_NUM))
                SERIAL_NUM
                FROM EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_RCV_SERIAL_TRANSACTIONS b,
                left join (SELECT DUM_ID,ACTUAL_SERIAL_NO
                FROM EDW_SERVICE_ETL_DB.SS.CSF_XXCTS_INV_SNO_CROSS_REF) a
                a.DUM_ID = b.SERIAL_NUM
                WHERE SHIPMENT_LINE_ID = P_ID1_I AND TRANSACTION_ID = P_ID2_I;

L_SN_CONCAT VARCHAR;

BEGIN
LET L_START       NUMBER := 0;
FOR C_SN_CUR in C_RECEIPT_SN DO
    IF L_START = 0
     THEN
        IF C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM IS NOT NULL
        THEN
           L_SN_CONCAT := C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM;
        END IF;
     ELSE
        IF C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM IS NULL
        THEN
           L_SN_CONCAT :=
              L_SN_CONCAT || P_DELIMITER_I || C_SN_CUR.SERIAL_NUM;
        END IF;
     END IF;
    L_START := L_START + 1;
END FOR;
RETURN L_SN_CONCAT;
END;
$$
;
```

> syntax error line 4 at position 0 unexpected 'C_RECEIPT_SN'. syntax
> error line 5 at position 37 unexpected 'a'. syntax error line 12 at
> position 16 unexpected 'WHERE'. (line 4

Comment: Hi - please update your question with Snowflake function that you’ve managed to write and the error message you’re getting

Comment: sure nick, let me edit my question, so you can see my script in snowflake.

Comment: You’re missing the word “on” before “  a.DUM_ID = b.SERIAL_NUM”

Comment: hi Nick, still getting the same error.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to show the latest version you have